# Java access enum field from outside

Tags: java, enums

How I can access the `Name` field?

```
public class Animals {

    public enum animal{
        a1("CAT", 4),
        a2("DOG", 4);
    }

    String Name;
    int E;
    public animal(String Name, int E){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.E    = E;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: Also your example has some compile errors. Please fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but you have a number of syntax errors. The key is to provide getter methods for the enum member variables.

```
public enum Animal {
  a1("CAT", 4), a2("DOG", 4);
  private String Name;
  private int E;

  private animal(String Name, int E)
  {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.E = E;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return Name;
  }

  public int getE() {
    return E;
  }
}
```

You could then access these values anywhere in the rest of your program.

```
Animal.a1.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an inner `enum` like this:

```
public class Animals {

    public enum Animal {
        a1("CAT", 4), a2("DOG", 4);

        final String Name;
        final int E;

        private Animal(String Name, int E) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.E = E;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

You *can* get the name using (field so no parenthesis)

```
Animals.Animal.a1.Name
```

but better to make all fields private and use the getter:

```
Animals.Animal.a1.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I believe the OP is asking:

“Given a string, "a1", return an object of type Animal with the value Animal.a1”

… in which case, the method you're looking for would be Enum.valueOf(Class,String)

```
 String enumName = "a1";
 Animal a = Enum.valueOf (Animal.class (enumName));
 if (null == a) {
      // error handler …
 } else {
      // do something interesting with “a”
 }
```